# Dependency 'javax:javaee-api:6.0' not found

Tags: java, intellij-idea, dependency-injection, dependencies, java-ee-6

I'm a computer science student and I'm currently making my first steps in using JEE. To retry an example of my study material, I tried to build a web-application using IntelliJ Community. As there is no offical possibility to do so with the community version, I tried to use maven following this tutorial: https://www.shortn0tes.com/2017/01/tutorial-intellij-idea-community.html

Now I get an error about the dependency injection of javax in the pom.xml:
**Dependency 'javax:javaee-api:6.0' not found**

Is there anything that I need to add/configure in my IntelliJ IDE? I know that the tutorial is maybe not super modern anymore, but I'd just like to follow the example of my university material.

Thank you very much!

Here my pom.xml:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>org.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>test</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <name>test Maven Webapp</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax</groupId>
      <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
      <version>6.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>test</finalName>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
          <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.2</version>
          <configuration>
            <port>8888</port>
            <path>/</path>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <configuration>
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- see http://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_war_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.2.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Where and when do you get this error? The build works for me for the project loaded from the given link.

Comment: If you are getting it during the Maven build - this looks like the Maven download dependency problem.

Comment: Hey! Thank you for your answer :) I don't know why but today I restarted my IDE with the project and there was no error anymore. I'm using IntelliJ Community with maven and when I typed in the dependencies in the pom.xml, the <groupid>javax</groupid> instantly turned red. The error was visible as soon as I hovered the mouse cursor over it